# OpenMP Target Task reduction

Tags: openmp, offloading

I'm using OpenMP target offloading do offload some nested loops to the gpu. I'm using the `nowait` to tun it asynchronous. This makes it a task. With the same input values the result differs from the one when not offloading (e.g. cpu: sum=0.99, offloading sum=0.5).
When removing the `nowait` clause it works just fine. So I think the issue is that it becomes an OpenMP task and I'm struggling getting it right.

```cpp
#pragma omp target teams distribute parallel for reduction( +: sum) collapse(2) nowait depend(in: a, b) depend(out: sum)
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
        {   
            double c = 0;
            
            for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
            {
                c += /* some computation */
            }
            
            sum += fabs(c); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: openMP to offload on the GPU? are you getting confused with openCL ?

Comment: No, since version 4.0 OpenMP provides offloading to GPUs.

Comment: Why don't you make summation in local variables (sum_local) and sum only once on outer loop for "sum"? Too many summations may add error right?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I'm aware of the fact that value of doubles might differ. For example for n=800 the result if running on the host is 0.9924 whereas when using Offloading I get 0.5491. And yes I'm passing same input values.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark you are totally right! Just edited it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [OpenMP 5.2 specification](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/OpenMP-API-Specification-5-2.pdf) states:

> The `target` construct generates a *target task*. The *generated task* region encloses the target region. If a `depend` clause is present, it is associated with the *target task*. [...]. If the `nowait` clause is present, execution of the *target task* may be deferred. If the `nowait` clause is not present, the *target task* is an *included task*.

This means that your code is executed **in a task** with a possibly **deferred execution** (with `nowait`). Thus, it can be executed at the end of the parallel in the worst case, but always before all the dependent tasks and `taskwait` directives waiting for the target task (or the ones including a similar behaviour like `taskgroup`). Because of that, you need not to modify the working arrays (nor release them) during this time span. If you do, the behaviour is undefined.

You should especially pay attention to the correctness of *synchronization points* and *task dependencies* in your code (it is impossible for us to check that with the current incomplete provided code).